# Inline pull load rating of lag bolts in wood?

Tags: fasteners, wood

Is there some sort of general guidance or load rating for wood screws (lag bolts) going into framing wood where the force is pulling directly inline with the screw orientation? More context and specifics:

Trying to install a ceiling attachment for a hoist in a garage. There is a structural beam going across the ceiling. Looking at the engineering plans I see the following:

- Size: 7x14
- Type: PSL (Parallel strand lumber)
- Bearing: 5-2x6 (not sure what this means?)

I can't access the top of the beam (drywall, floor joists, etc) so hoping to use lag bolts (drilled vertically up into the beam) to attach a lashing ring (to which I would attach a block-and-tackle or chain hoist). Here's a little diagram:

[image]

I'm assuming there is some engineering reference table where you can see the rated load depending on the screw type, shank diameter, thread pitch, wood type, and length of screw inserted in the material?

I tried to search the web but I'll admit I don't even know what terms to search for.

My intuition tells me to use a lashing ring plate with 4 holes and use bigger (3/8 and longer) lag screws, but I'll admit I just even have an idea. Is vertical pull on a 1/4 lag bolt 50 lbs or 500 lbs?

Also to qualify: I'm not lifting anything insane. Most likely only lifting about 250 lbs, but would be nice to know if it's possible to lift a car engine for example.

I was also told to use GRK Fasteners 'RSS' screws instead of traditional lag screws. I'm guessing they have more holding power because of the aggressive thread?

I'm a software engineer not a civil engineer so completely a fish out of water, but also don't want to just take the advice from the ol' Home Depot boys "oh she'll be fine, ya, just use a few screws"...

Comment: I don't think people use 1/4" lag bolts even for gymnastic rings setups. We use 1/2" lag bolts 4" long. I am only 120lbs and don't do dynamic loads so I only need two, but I use three and did not need to look any harder since I don't weigh that much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cases, where access is an issue like yours, AWC (American Wood Council) has a design guide handout for lag screw withdrawal resistance values, [link](https://awc.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/AWC-DA1-LagScrew-0702.pdf). This has to be used as design value in conjunction with National Design Specification (NDS) for Wood Construction.

Depending on the method of calculation, like LFRD (load and Resistance) factored or ASD (allowable stress design, allowable strength design). also, there are factors for the load duration, moisture content of the beam,...etc.

It would basically boil down to a factor of safety of around 1.8.
I would choose a factor of safety of 3. I am adding a page of the AWC tables here just as an example.

'

[image: table]

Comment: Thanks for the link and explanation, super helpful! I'll admit, I'm not an engineer so having a bit of a tough time understanding some of the terms. Looks like the table has figures around shear, which I'm assuming is force applied perpendicular to the bolt orientation. I couldn't figure out which of the Z column values pertained to withdrawal force?

Comment: Found a 'connection calculator': https://awc.org/calculators/connection-calculator/

This allows you to calculate both withdrawal loading and lateral loading. I'm thinking I'll go with a 3/8x6" lag, which seems to provide a rating of 770lbs in softwood (spruce-pine-fir). In my application the lag is going into engineered lumber, which I'm assuming has a much higher specific gravity vs even natural hardwoods. If I switch the calculator to run of Oak the withdrawal loading calculator states over 1500lbs! So I'm guessing with two 3/8 lags I'm at 3000 lbs, which is way above my 300lbs weight!

Answer (score 0):

I found the following resource: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/wood-screws-allowable-withdrawal-load-d_1815.html

The calculator requires the Specific Gravity of wood, wasn't able to find it for PSL but for fir (which is common for dimensional lumber in my area) the value is 0.45 (pretty soft wood!)

Assuming 3/8" lag screws:
[image]

Looks like the withdrawal force is actually crazy high just for one screw, so with 2 or 4 screws I'm way above (more than x3) on the load I hope to lift.

Answer (score 0):

If you would make a U-shape clamp around the beam, you could bolt it to the sides of the beam. You can put as many bolts as you need (or a threaded bar right through) at the neutral line of the beam.

The vertical load would load the bolts or bar by a shear force. I expect the permissible shear load of a bolt to be listed somewhere, or otherwise to be calculated by cross-section area * bolt class yield strength * 0.55

Comment: That was my hope initially, but I can't really access the sides of the beam easily. Not without ripping up a bunch of the ceiling drywall. I definitely agree that the shear load would be way higher in this situation! From the online calculators I've seen (referenced above) I think I'm looking at withdrawal force of something like 770lbs for a 3/8x6 lag in softwood like pine! My beam is engineered PSL, so I'm guessing behaves more like a hardwood. So 2 bolts @ 770 lbs each minimum gives me a huge buffer if I'm lifting only 250-300lbs. So I'm guessing I'll be fine..